# Python web-scraping issue: unable to retrieve body section data from a specific URL

Tags: python, web-scraping

Unable to retrieve data from the body section while attempting web scraping using Python.

I am facing an issue where I am unable to retrieve data from the body section while performing web scraping using Python. I would appreciate some assistance with this problem.

Python Code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url_kakao = "https://www.kakaopay.com/news/pr"
headers = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/**********"}
 # The user-agent information may be considered confidential, so it has been replaced with "*"

res_kakao = requests.get(url_kakao, headers=headers)
res_kakao.raise_for_status()

soup_kakao = BeautifulSoup(res_kakao.text,'lxml')
kakao = soup_kakao.find_all("div",attrs={"class":"css-1mqcdgs e2lpi48"})
print(kakao)
```

→ conclusion : NONE

The reason for the output being 'NONE' is likely because the data from the body section is not being successfully scraped.

Is web scraping not possible on the url_kakao website?

Comment: What's the ourput of `res_kakao.text` if it doesn't have the html body then html might be getting loaded dynaically, and you will have to look for selenium

Comment: I went to "https://www.kakaopay.com/news/pr", clicked on "view source" and there is no match with `css-1mqcdgs e2lpi48`.

Comment: @Peter Thank you for your response.

When I learned web scraping, I was taught to open the developer tools (F12) of a website and scrape the elements visible there. However, as you mentioned, when I viewed the page source, I couldn't find the corresponding code. I'm not sure why it's not appearing either! Perhaps it's because the page is written in JavaScript, as mentioned in the previous response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Content is loaded dynamically via JavaScript from an api:

```
import requests

requests.get('https://www.kakaopay.com/brand-api/news?page=0&size=10&locale=ko').json()
```

Simply adapt the request and adjust the the value for the `page` parameter.

```
{'list': [{'id': 278,
   'news_contents_category': 'COMMON',
   'title': '5월, 카카오페이로 편의점 결제하면 무제한 혜택이!',
   'present_dttm': '2023. 5. 17.'},
  {'id': 277,
   'news_contents_category': 'COMMON',
   'title': '카카오페이, "3년 내 연 100억 건의 금융 니즈 해결 목표"',
   'present_dttm': '2023. 5. 15.'},
  {'id': 276,
   'news_contents_category': 'COMMON',
   'title': '카카오페이증권, ‘매일 이자 받기’ 서비스 시작',
   'present_dttm': '2023. 5. 4.'},...]}
```

With the `id` from the JSON you could call the articles https://www.kakaopay.com/news/pr_detail?id=278